# Is there a way to tell TeamCity's AssemblyInfo Patcher to only change AssemblyFileVersion (and leave AssemblyVersion alone)

Tags: teamcity

I am using TeamCity to build a large solution with many components, but many of which may be referenced by DLLs built separately (ie not built by TeamCity)

This means that if I use the AssemblyInfo Patcher, the 'external' DLLs tend to stop working as they were built referencing a different AssemblyVersion.

I really want to have the AssemblyFileVersion updating so users can accurately report which build they are using, but I don't want the AssemblyVersion to be touched. If I leave the AssemblyVersion field blank in the patcher, it simply defaults to %build.number%.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the File Content Replacer feature instead. I had a similar problem to you and switched to File Content Replacer. It even has a built-in template that will do the trick for you.

[Team City Documentation on File Content Replacer](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/File+Content+Replacer)